# I need Ubuntu Desktop for developers. Can someone mail it to me

Tags: mail, livedvd

I don't have enough Megabytes for downloading the Ubuntu Desktop for developers.

Can anyone mail me the copy?
It would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you...

Vivian,
Papua New Guinea.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the installation disk from:

http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/developers.

However, if you want to get the CD or DVD, you can try to get it from:

http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17